# scala user input is taken correctly, but not displayed during the typing

Tags: scala, cygwin

I am writing a simple code to take in user input age (double) and print out cube of the value that was input.

Please see code and the run session below (I ran it within a cygwin window):

My question is, when I type in the value on the console, I never see it getting typed even though the whole process works and I get the right output back.

```
$ cat user_input_function.scala
// write some text out to the user with Console.println
Console.println("Hello")

// Console is imported by default, so it's not really needed, just use   println
```

println("World")

```
// readInt lets you read an Int, but you have to prompt the user manually
```

print("How old are you? ")
    val age = readDouble()

```
def cubed (x: Double) = x * x * x
//val a = 10
val b = cubed(age)
println (b)

u0124587@U0124587-TPL-B ~
$ scala user_input_function.scala
warning: there was one deprecation warning; re-run with -deprecation for     details
one warning found
Hello
World
How old are you? 1030.301
```

u0124587@U0124587-TPL-B ~
$

Thanks. Any help is sincerely appreciated.

Comment: I typed 10.1 after How old are you? That "10.1" does not show up on the screen.

Comment: Your program should work either in a linux environment, or from a Windows CMD.EXE shell (or other non-cygwin shell).   It might also possible to get it to work in a cygwin shell by issuing the right stty command beforehand.  The problem is you're running Windows java in a non-Windows command line shell.